# How can I change the width of the input box?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the width of an inout box in the header of my website, but am unable to. I have tried using `style= "width: Xpx"` but it does not work.

Could someone be so kind to help me out?

```
<div class="input-group">
    <label for="Email" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'contact.form.email' | t }}</label>
      <input type="email" style="margin: 0" style="width:250px;" value="{% if customer %}{{ customer.email }}{% endif %}" placeholder="{{ 'general.newsletter_form.newsletter_email' | t }}" name="contact[email]" id="Email" class="input-group-field" aria-label="{{ 'layout.footer.newsletter_email_placeholder' | t }}" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">  
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" name="commit" id="subscribe" style="font-size: 16px;">{{ 'general.newsletter_form.submit' | t }}</button>
      </span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

> In HTML, SGML and XML, attributes cannot be repeated, and should
>   only be defined in an element once.

In your HTML you have 2 style attributes written.. See below

```
<input type="email" style="margin: 0" style="width:250px;"
```

**This is non-conformant to the HTML standard, and will result in undefined behaviour, and thus will be rendered differently by different browsers.**

In HTML, when you use the same attributes more than once, only the first one will take into effect in most of the browsers. Thus, for your styles to work, you should change your HTML as follows

```
<input type="email" style="margin: 0;width:250px;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Lals answer is correct. Alternatively, move your width settings to a CSS class, and lose the style completely from the HTML. You don't need to add a class to the element, you can reference it because its inside a div labelled `class="input-group"`. Like so :

```
<input type="email" value="{% if customer %}....
```

in the CSS stylesheet (.css file) add:

```
.input-group input[type="email"]{
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    max-width:300px;
}
```

this will style any input of type "email", which appears inside a div with class="input-group". You won't have to set the width every time. To change ALL input boxes in input-groups, it would be:

```
.input-group input{
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    max-width:300px;
}
```